# AutoCad NET Send String to Execute Synchronously

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad

In my AutoCad addon I have been using the Document.SendStringToExecute function to execute Lisp commands, manually concatenating the commands into strings. However, I now want to have my addon apply to multiple drawings, which becomes awkward when using the asynchronous command.

I now want to make these commands synchronous. All of them call the sub LispCommand() so I could change the method afterwards.

```
Sub LispCommand(cmd as String)
doc.SendStringToExecute(cmd, False, False, True)
End Sub
```

I have tried P/Invoking acedCmd, however it appears you can only pass an argument array to it, and I want (if possible) to be able to use my existing full string, e.g. "(c:ace_new_wiretype "RED" (list) "")"

Is there any way to send a contatenated string command to AutoCad synchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I use it on AutoCAD 2012 and 2013. Try Command method and ExecuteStringOverInvoke method. Remove the logger if you will.

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Castle.Core.Logging;
using AcadApp = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application;


namespace YourCAD.Utilities
{
    using System.Reflection;

    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static class CommandLineHelper
    {
        private const string ACAD_EXE = "acad.exe";

        private const short RTSTR = 5005;

        private const short RTNORM = 5100;

        private const short RTNONE = 5000;

        private const short RTREAL = 5001;

        private const short RT3DPOINT = 5009;

        private const short RTLONG = 5010;

        private const short RTSHORT = 5003;

        private const short RTENAME = 5006;

        private const short RTPOINT = 5002; /*2D point X and Y only */

        private static Dictionary<Type, short> resTypes = new Dictionary<Type, short>();

        private static ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;

        public static ILogger Logger
        {
            get
            {
                return _logger;
            }
            set
            {
                _logger = value;
            }
        }

        static CommandLineHelper()
        {
            resTypes[typeof(string)] = RTSTR;
            resTypes[typeof(double)] = RTREAL;
            resTypes[typeof(Point3d)] = RT3DPOINT;
            resTypes[typeof(ObjectId)] = RTENAME;
            resTypes[typeof(Int32)] = RTLONG;
            resTypes[typeof(Int16)] = RTSHORT;
            resTypes[typeof(Point2d)] = RTPOINT;
        }

        private static TypedValue TypedValueFromObject(Object val)
        {
            if (val == null) throw new ArgumentException("null not permitted as command argument");
            short code = -1;

            if (resTypes.TryGetValue(val.GetType(), out code) && code > 0)
            {
                return new TypedValue(code, val);
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type in Command() method");
        }

        public static int Command(params object[] args)
        {
            if (AcadApp.DocumentManager.IsApplicationContext) throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid execution context");
            int stat = 0;
            int cnt = 0;
            using (ResultBuffer buffer = new ResultBuffer())
            {
                foreach (object o in args)
                {
                    buffer.Add(TypedValueFromObject(o));
                    ++cnt;
                }
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
#if acad2012
                    stat = acedCmd2012(buffer.UnmanagedObject);
#endif
#if acad2013
                    stat = acedCmd2013( buffer.UnmanagedObject );
#endif

                }
            }
            return stat;
        }


        //[DllImport("acad.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?acedSetCurrentVPort@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@PBVAcDbViewport@@@Z")]
        //extern static private int acedCmd2013(IntPtr acDbVport);

        //[DllImport("acad.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?acedSetCurrentVPort@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@PBVAcDbViewport@@@Z")]
        //extern static private int acedCmd2008(IntPtr acDbVport);

        //[DllImport("acad.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?acedSetCurrentVPort@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@PEBVAcDbViewport@@@Z")]
        //extern static int acedCmd2011(IntPtr resbuf);

        [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("accore.dll", EntryPoint = "acedCmd", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int acedCmd2013(IntPtr resbuf);

        //[DllImport("acad.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "acedCmd")]
        [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [DllImport("acad.exe", EntryPoint = "acedCmd", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int acedCmd2012(IntPtr resbuf);

        public static void ExecuteStringOverInvoke(string command)
        {
            try
            {
#if acad2012
                object activeDocument =
                    Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.AcadDocument;
#endif

#if acad2013
                object activeDocument = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentExtension.GetAcadDocument(
                    Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument);
#endif
                object[] data = { command };
                activeDocument.GetType()
                              .InvokeMember(
                                  "SendCommand", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, activeDocument, data);
            }
            catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Error("Command line class error.", exception);
            }
        }

        static MethodInfo runCommand = typeof(Editor).GetMethod(
            "RunCommand", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        public static PromptStatus Command(this Editor ed, params object[] args)
        {
            if (Application.DocumentManager.IsApplicationContext)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid execution context for Command()");
            }
            if (ed.Document != Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Document is not active");
            }
            return (PromptStatus)runCommand.Invoke(ed, new object[] { args });
        }
    }

    public class CommandLineShortCuts
    {
        // Sample member functions that use the Command() method.

        public static int ZoomExtents()
        {
            return CommandLineHelper.Command("._ZOOM", "_E");
        }

        public static int ZoomCenter(Point3d center, double height)
        {
            return CommandLineHelper.Command("._ZOOM", "_C", center, height);
        }

        public static int ZoomWindow(Point3d corner1, Point3d corner2)
        {
            return CommandLineHelper.Command("._ZOOM", "_W", corner1, corner2);
        }

        public static int SetFilletRadius(double filletRadius)
        {
            return CommandLineHelper.Command("._FILLET", "_R", filletRadius);
        }

        public static int FilletPolyline(ObjectId polylineId)
        {
            return CommandLineHelper.Command("._FILLET", "_P", polylineId);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Application.Invoke`:

```
 var rb = new ResultBuffer(new TypedValue[] {
   new TypedValue((int) LispDataType.Text, "c:ace_new_wiretype"),
   new TypedValue((int) LispDataType.Text, "RED"),  
   new TypedValue((int) LispDataType.ListBegin, null), 
   new TypedValue((int) LispDataType.ListEnd, null), 
   new TypedValue((int) LispDataType.Text, "")
 });
 Application.Invoke(rb);
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks @Maxence I don't suppose there's a way to invoke one string only, rather than passing each parameter individually (like my Sub LispCommand above)?

Comment: May be. There is a lot of ways to call commands & lisp functions: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/08/techniques_for_.html?cid=6a00d83452464869e2014e602fd641970c#comment-6a00d83452464869e2014e602fd641970c and https://sites.google.com/site/acadhowtodo/net/command-line/run-lisp-functions